# How to install extension in Safari by AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript

I need to perform automatic installation extension in Safari.

Now I have this part of code:

```
property extension_list : {"safariextz"}
  on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
  try
    tell application "Finder"
      repeat with i from 1 to (number of items in these_items)
      set this_item to item i of these_items
      set item_extension to name extension of this_item 
        if item_extension = "safariextz" then
        tell application "Safari" to open this_item
      delete this_item
        end if
      end repeat
    end tell
on error errmsg
    display dialog errmsg buttons {"OK"} default button 1 
  end try
end adding folder items to
```

This works, file is running after downloading.
But I cannot press button Install for starting installation extension.

I tried something like that

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Safari"
    click the button "Install"
  end tell
end tell
```

But this doesn't help.
Cloud you please assist to me with completing script for extension installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify a window like this : `click button 1 of window 1`

open an "safariextz" file in Safari blocks the script, you must use `ignoring application responses`

The script must check that the dialog is displayed

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with this_item in these_items
        if (this_item as string) ends with ".safariextz" then
            ignoring application responses
                tell application "Safari" to open this_item
            end ignoring
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Safari"
                    set frontmost to true
                    repeat until (exists window 1) and subrole of window 1 is "AXDialog" -- wait until the dialog is displayed.
                        delay 1
                    end repeat
                    click button 1 of front window -- install
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Updated : as `ignoring application responses` doesn't work for you, try this

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
        repeat with this_item in these_items
            if (this_item as string) ends with ".safariextz" then
                    tell application "Finder" to open this_item
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!
I checked button in Accessibility Inspector, it has number 3.
So I updated this line: click button 3 of front window -- install
But unfortunately this doesn't help, I still haven't pressed button by script.
I've been waiting about 1 minute and after that message "Safari got an error: AppleEvent timed out" appears.
Can it be related to ignoring process? May be something wrong in my script with ignoring and it doesn't go ahead after code: tell application "Safari" to open this_item

Comment: The "GUI Scripting" varies depending on the version of the OS and Safari. 
My script works on Safari 7.0.5 and OS X 10.9.4

Comment: Here, I have only two buttons in this window. try this: add `set frontmost to true` after `tell process "Safari"`

Comment: hi @jackjr300 I'm trying to run exactly this but i'm getting erratic results, sometimes the button is click other times it sticks. Also when running it as a launchagent it never ever clicks the button, as soon as the dialog pops up the script stops - is there anyway around that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

For Safari 9, the button's context changed.  Here's the script I figured out to get it back working. (*This is only to show the order of commands and how to click the button.*)

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 2 
tell application "System Events" 
    tell application process "Safari" 
        set frontmost to true
        tell application "Safari" to open location "/path/to/SafariDriver.safariextz" 
        delay 2 
        click button 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell 
end tell 
tell application "Safari" to quit
```